# Observable not triggered when using asObservable() with Subject in Angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I have a component that displays a form to a user. Once user selects the submit button on that form I would like to trigger an http.post request to the backend

I want to use BehaviorSubject and .asObservable() witht he | async pipe to achieve this.

I have the following set up in my `PreOrderComponenT` component ts file:

`preOrder$ = this.preOrderService.preOrder$;`

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.preOrderForm);
    const preOrderForm: PreOrderForm = {
      firstName: this.preOrderForm.value.firstName,
      lastName: this.preOrderForm.value.lastName,
      phoneNumber: this.preOrderForm.value.phoneNumber,
      email: this.preOrderForm.value.email,
      orderDetails: {
        quantity: this.preOrderForm.value.orderDetails.quantity,
        size: this.preOrderForm.value.orderDetails.size,
        gearItemId: this.gearItem.id
      },
      contactPreference: {
        cellOrEmail: this.preOrderForm.value.contactPreference.cellOrEmail
      }
    };
    this.preOrderService.preOrderGearItem(preOrderForm);
  }
```

In the `PreOrderComponent` I have the following in the template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="preOrderService.preOrder$ | async as preOrderItem">
  <div> TEST </div>
</ng-container>
```

In the `PreOrderService` I have the following:

```
    preOrderAction: BehaviorSubject<PreOrderForm> = new BehaviorSubject<
        PreOrderForm
      >(null);

      preOrder$ = this.preOrderAction.asObservable().pipe(
        switchMap((preOrderForm: PreOrderForm) => {
          console.log("PreORderTriggered");
          return this.preOrderGearItemAsync(preOrderForm);
        })
      );

    preOrderGearItem(preOrderForm: PreOrderForm) {
        console.log("Pre order form is:", preOrderForm);
        this.preOrderAction.next(preOrderForm);
      }

    preOrderGearItemAsync(preOrderForm: PreOrderForm): Observable<PreOrderForm> {
        if (preOrderForm === undefined) {
          return of(null);
        }
        return this.http
          .post<PreOrderForm>(
            `${this.merchandiseUrl}/${
              preOrderForm.orderDetails.gearItemId
            }/pre-order`,
            JSON.stringify(preOrderForm),
            this.headers
          )
}
```

The problem is that I cannot get the http request to be triggered. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: To make it work - `this.preOrderGearItemAsync(preOrderForm).pipe(finalise(() => this.preOrderAction.next(preOrderForm))).subscribe()` in `preOrderGearItem` method.

Comment: Hi. See my answer below. Are you sure there isn't any issue with http post request. No need to serialize your model to Json. Could you check ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is "working", as you can see with this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nm5pcd

However, may I underline 2 points, and propose you improvments ?

**1) http request is called immediately at service initialization (even without submit)**

This occurs because of "null" first value of `BehaviourSubject`, and because `=== undefined` should be `=== null`. Or even better, you could use `filter` operator.

```
preOrder$ = this.preOrderAction.asObservable().pipe(
  filter((preOrderForm: PreOrderForm) => !!preOrderForm),
  switchMap((preOrderForm: PreOrderForm) => {
    return this.preOrderGearItemAsync(preOrderForm);
  })
);
```

**2) You could also consider another way to invoke your post request.**

a) Solution A

Keep it very simple. 
So just call `service.preOrderGearItemAsync` from your component, subscribe, retrieve result and display it.

```
this.preOrderService.preOrderGearItemAsync(preOrderForm).subscribe(response => {
  this.result = response;
});
```

b) Solution B

As shown in `NewPreOrderService` in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nm5pcd.

Your component could call method `preOrderGearItem` which invoke `http.get` by subscribing, and then call `next` on `BehaviourSubject` to keep last result available to your component.

Hope it will help.